# Managing thread from a mouseclick

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

May be it is a basic question. But I'm a little confused about it. In my design I've a thread that is started from a mouse click. Method looks something like this:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable(){
public void run(){
A.firstMethod();
A.SecondMethod();
B.FirstMethod();
B.SecondMethod();
B.ThirdMethod();
}
};
new Thread(r).start();
```

Here     `B.FirstMethod(), B.SecondMethod(), B.ThirdMethod();` are accessing same variables and do some database operations during execution (i.e. locking, reading, writing etc.). But, If mouse is clicked during the execution or before finishing all the tasks I often get error message from database. How can I handle such type of situations. Here I cannot force the user to wait just with a simple Progressbar.

Comment: use locks for synchronization and popup windows to restrict the user to wait.

Answer (score 0):

To handle such situation, you can disable the button once the thread has started its execution, and enable it again once the thread is going to finish its execution.
The code will then look like following:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
  public void run()
  {
    button.setEnabled(false);
    A.FirstMethod();
    A.SecondMethod();
    B.FirstMethod();
    B.SecondMethod();
    B.ThirdMethod();
    button.setEnabled(true);
  }
};

new Thread(r).start();
```

Or when the button is clicked, you can use a boolean variable to check if the thread is in progress or not, and then decide as to what needs to be done like:

```
volatile boolean inProgress = false; // Instance Variable
Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
  public void run()
  {
    inProgress = true;
    A.FirstMethod();
    A.SecondMethod();
    B.FirstMethod();
    B.SecondMethod();
    B.ThirdMethod();
    inProgress = false;
  }
};

if(!inProgress)
  new Thread(r).start();
else
  Popup some message perhaps
```